# Compare start and end dates across multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, exists, postgresql-8.4

I have a table of subscriptions for contacts. A contact can have multiple subscriptions:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE subscription (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    contact_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES contact(id),
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I need to get all subscriptions for a given by contact that do **not** have a subscription
that starts on the same date as the end date of the another subscription for the same
contact.

So for the given data:

```
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES 
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Frank');

INSERT INTO subscription (id, contact_id, start_date, end_date) VALUES 
(1, 1, '2012-01-01', '2013-01-01'),
(2, 1, '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01'),
(3, 2, '2012-01-01', '2012-09-01'),
(4, 2, '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01');
```

I want to get subscriptions with ids of 2, 3, 4 but not 1, because the contact 'John'
has a subscription with a `start_date` on the same day (`2013-01-01`) as the `end_date` 
for subscription with `id` of 1.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Fixed a typo, but I like how you provided a proper test case. +1 Note, however, that your text contradicts itself. A query `for a given contact` can never return `2, 3, 4`, since `2` belongs to a separate contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/55e67/2)

```
select *
from subscription s0
where not exists (
    select 1
    from subscription s1
    where
        s0.contact_id = s1.contact_id
        and s1.start_date = s0.end_date
)
order by contact_id, id
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't exhaustive enough in the example data in my question, but, from what I can tell, this solution won't work if there are more than two subscriptions per contact. See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dffb3/1/0).

Comment: @Divey I [updated the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/55e67/1) with more than 2 subscriptions per contact. Post more data to test it.

Comment: Using your fiddle, the subscription with an id of 4 should not appear in the results. It has an end_date of '2014-01-01', which is the start_date for the next subscription (id 5).